# Blender stops rendering when objects are rotated?

Tags: rendering, transforms

I'm attempting to render a simple scene with 3 magazines fanned out on a plane, but for some reason, whenever I rotate a magazine and go to render, the render stops at 4 tiles. It doesn't do this when I *don't* rotate any of the magazines, it renders just fine.

Starting from scratch gave me the same result.

Is this a bug or could there be something else going on? If it's a bug it's a rather serious one. Why would Blender be unable to render a scene just because an object's been rotated?

Comment: Could you provide a .blend file? Thanks.

Comment: That's odd... Try applying the rotation by pressing [Ctrl] + [A]>Rotation. Are you using 2.72b?

Comment: How long are you giving it to render? It could just be getting stuck on those tiles.

Comment: What renderer and material types are involved too? If it's a semiglossy magazine using cycles or scattering it's concieveable that the move just increased the light complexity of the scene a lot. … But for answers instead of wild ass-guesses please upload the file or at least some screenshots to pasteall or somewhere and give links.

Comment: Please provide a Blend file, it's a curious problem but without something to play with, it's hard to say what's causing it.